# Random characters being added to url in address bar (Session?)

Tags: session, url, address-bar

In the address bar of my web app the pages are displayed correctly but in the address bar there is an added set of characters in the format `(S(<random chars>))`

Example:

`http://test/(S(x0ovoq55mlxrca45gx505h45))/default.aspx`

The characters change each time, but I assume it has something to do with the session. I just don't know how to get rid of it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so worked it out. It was to do with the session. In the web.config I had sessionState cookieless attribute set to true. Setting it to false removes the random chars.

Seems simple now I know!